# How to modify the default world generator

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, spigot

I'm currently working on a spigot server plugin and I want to modify the default world generator so that every chunk is made out of one random block. I heard that you can make a custom world generator but I only want to modify the default one. Is there any way to do that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`WorldCreator`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/WorldCreator.html) like that:

```java
new WorldCreator("myWorld").environment(Environment.NORMAL).generator(new MyGenerator()).createWorld();
```

Then, create the class `MyGenerator` which should extend [`ChunkGenerator`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/generator/ChunkGenerator.html) like that:

```java
public class MyGenerator extends ChunkGenerator {

   // here define all methods from "ChunkGenerator" class like:
   @Override
   public boolean shouldGenerateCaves() {
       return false;
   }
}
```

You can change some configuration in the world creator, specially the name or the seed. Else, you should config other things in the MyGenerator's class.

Comment: Oh and how can I do something like the setRegion method of the chunk data class?

Comment: @JohannesBecker the set region ? what do you mean ?

Comment: In ChunkGenerator.ChunkData (https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/generator/ChunkGenerator.ChunkData.html) I saw the Method setRegion() and I thought it would fit to my problem but it didnt. Is there any way to replace every block in a chunk?